# iPhone autolayout confusion

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder, autolayout

I want to put 2 **UIButtons** next to one another as per the screenshot below.  Also shown are the constraints settings for the first **UIButton**.

[image]

Those **UIButton** should scale up or down to suit iPhone 5, 6 or 6 plus.  But below is what I see on iPhone 5.

[image]

Where have i missed the constraint to add?

Comment: you can go with this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the horizontal line and mark it as dark red which means the button should expand in that direction in case of the width increases

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Put both the buttons in UIView.
2.set constraints to UIView(Leading,Trailing,Top,Height)
3.set the satisfying constraints to the two buttons.
```

I think this will put you through.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a container view.

```
button1.aspectratio = 1:1
button2.width = button1.width
button2.aspectratio = 1:1

button1.top to superview = 20
button1.leading to superview = 20
button1.trailing to button2.leading = 20
button2.top to superview = 20
button2.trailing to superview = 20
```

To add the aspect ration constraints just ctrl-drag from the button to itself (in the left pane).

[image]